# Symantec Endpoint Protection "portscan attack" false alarms?

Tags: firewall, symantec, port-scanning, torrent, symantec-endpoint-protection

On two Windows 7 machines in my LAN I have Symantec Endpoint Protection 12.1 installed. Things work fine, but several time per day I get to see the following warning:

[image: portscan]

I had a thorough look at the machine that is running on 192.168.1.111, but I am quite sure there is no malicious software on there. What could be triggering this alarm? The only thing I can think of is utorrent local peer discovery, although I that is not exactly a "port scan".

Comment: Is 192.168.1.111 a Windows machinge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tool that might help your situation is [Wire Shark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  This will let you see exactly whats going on in your network to see what might be hitting those machines and if it trully is a port scan.